# Как БЫСТРО решать олимпиадную задачу?

Tags: алгоритм

[Вот](http://codeforces.com/contest/558/problem/A) к примеру, простейшая олимпиадная задача. Я её решил за 45 минут, по старинке, с ооп:

1. Создаю класс AppleTree
2. Пишу компаратор
3. Делаю динамический массив и сортирую его
4. Применяю пару костылей чтобы знать где ближайшие деревья к нулевой позиции
5. Клонирую динамический массив
6. Рекурсивно хожу по массиву, удаляя деревья
7. Потом заход в другую строну по склонированному массиву

Вот это всё с учётом поиска багов заняло у меня три четверти часа. А если посмотреть, то некоторым людям удавалось решить её за 5 минут!

Ну за 5 мин у меня точно не получится. Но хотя бы за 20...

Ну и вопрос как этого добиться. Поскольку подавляющее кол-во времени заняла писанина, то надо её как-то уменьшить. Но как это сделать? **Я понимаю, что не нужно городить оопгород, но как его не городить?**

p.s. Тем, кто будет предлагать закрыть вопрос за "необходимо конкретизировать вопрос" и т.п. - я специально привёл конкретную задачу. По моему это достаточная конкретизация.

Comment: У людей которые занимаются олимпиадным программированием обычно в некоторый момент набирается огромное количество алгоритмических шаблонов. Они буквально копипастят готовый шаблон  и быстро правят его. Кроме того задачи вроде "рекурсивно обойти массив" не вызывают у них размышлений совсем и вылетают из-под пальцев вообще без багов. Потому что они их решали сотню-другую раз. Вот оттуда 5 минут и берется

Comment: Конкретно эта задаче решается куда меньшими усилиями:

Comment: @Yaant а именно?

Comment: Это я не дописал — нажал энтер для переноса строки, а комментарий взял и запостился. :)
Итак:
1) Заливаем исходные данные в зависимости от знака x_i в два отсортированных по модулю x массива.
2) суммируем значения a_i из обоих массивов от 0 до n, где n — длина меньшего из массивов (считая, что индексация массивов начинается с 0, и a[length(a)] = 0).
Собственно, все.

Answer (score 3):

> Я понимаю, что не нужно городить оопгород, но как его не городить?

Одна функция, а то и просто пару строк в main.
Все олимпиадные задачи делятся на несколько типов:

- **На реализацию:** (требует знание определенного алгоритма и умения его быстро и правильно запедалить).
- **На смекалку:** (по типу ответ всегда одинаковый или их 2 возможных, для этого вам следует на листочку натренироваться решать задачи и вычислять алгоритмические закономерности).
- **Брут форс:** (задачи которые решаются полным перебором, для таких задач необходим достаточный опыт и правильное умении алгоритмической сложности, что бы заранее оценить успеет ли ваш алгоритм дать правильный ответ).
- **Разделяй и властвуй:** (некоторые задачи при разбиении их на подзадачи решаются в 4 строки).
- **Сведение задач к существующим:** (при достаточном опыте вы сможете одни задачи сводить к другим).

А вобще, кроме опыта вам не чего не поможет, все задачи в основном решаются в 10-25 строк кода (кроме пункта 1, но их не так много). Выучите как можно лучше STL и вперед. **Сначала вы должны знать алгоритм который пишите, а уже после его писать!**

Answer (score 2):

Тема на самом деле не достаточно конкретная, ибо спрашивается совсем не о задаче.

А рецепт тут только один, и он очень "прост": набивать руку, решать как можно больше задач, тогда типовые решения будут реализовываться "на автомате". Ну и разбирать чужие хорошие решения, перенимая правильные практики.